# Angular: Remove tag if attribute selector used

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a button component defined as

*button.component.ts*

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button, [app-button]',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

*button.component.html*

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="clicked.emit()">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

which is used in other components as

*parent.component.html*

```html
<div class="col">
  <app-button>Click Here</app-button>
</div>
```

This renders the `app-button` component before rendering the `button` tag, as

```html
<div class="col">
  <app-button>
    <button ...></button>
  </app-button>
</div>
```

In few cases, I do not want to render the `app-button` tag between the `div` and `button`. For that I can use the attribute selector instead `[app-button]` like

```html
<div class="col">
  <button app-button>Click Here</button>
</div>
```

But it is rendering `button` twice (because the element is there in the `app-button` as well).

```html
<div class="col">
  <button>
    <button ...></button>
  </button>
</div>
```

Is it possible to detect if the component is rendered using **attribute-selector** or direct selector and remove the `button` tag from inside the component?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the presence of the attribute in the component host:

```js
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('app-button') === null) {
      console.log('It\'s rendered through tag selector');
    } else {
      console.log('It\'s rendered through attribute selector');

      // Hide your button tag inside the component
    }
  }
```